# About Nuget Package Manager for VS 2013

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget-package

I would like to know
1. Where the Nuget Package manager installed in c drive

2. When try to check the NuGet installed version using PowerShell script
   I am getting old version instead of installed version in VS 2013.
3. I am trying to view the version and folder where it has installed.

Comment: At the root of C: from your command prompt look for all instances of nuget.exe

Comment: Hi Sawrub  , No I don't see any nugget.exe . I would like to know where it had installed and how to get version programatically .

Answer (score 0):

You can see your local nuget packages in %windows drive%:\Users\your user.nuget\packages

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But I don't see any folder as mentioned. Note : Vs 2013 and Windows OS 10.

Comment: You mean, you don't have this folder *C:\Users\Mehrdad\.nuget\packages* ? of course, you should change *Mehrdad* with your user.

Comment: Sorry , I was confused be because I have two username in Users folder. But I don't see any folder inside that

Comment: I mean , after this I don't see any folder. C:\Users\janardhan\.nuget\packages

Comment: Yes I have logged in

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
(Get-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -ListAvailable).ProviderPath
```

This will give you the path to NuGet installations

In your position, I'd just go ahead and install the latest version of NuGet (Run as Administrator):

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope AllUsers
```

Comment: After trying that "unable to find package provider 'nuget'

Comment: For the Get, or the Install? If you post the actual errors it would help. Just edit your original post with what you;ve tried and the results. Try just "Get-PackageProvider" on its own.

Comment: Hi Scepticalist, I would like find the NuGet Package installed version.
If i try to find version using powershell i am getting v2.7 but i have installed v2.12.